# I want to solve my Sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

```
SELECT 
    a.studentcode, 
    a.studentname, 
    a.fathername, 
    a.date, 
    c.centrename, 
    cm.feename, 
    l.location, 
    a.periodofissue, 
    a.image 
FROM admission a 
INNER JOIN centre c ON a.centreid = c.id 
INNER JOIN coursemaster cm ON a.courseid = cm.id 
INNER JOIN location l ON a.locationid = l.id where a.id in (".$pc.")
```

and after executing the query an error occured that is:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`)`' at line 
>       1 `SELECT a.studentcode, a.studentname, a.fathername, a.date, c.centrename, cm.feename, l.location, a.periodofissue, a.image FROM admission a 
>       INNER JOIN centre c ON a.centreid = c.id INNER JOIN coursemaster cm ON a.courseid = cm.id INNER JOIN location l ON a.locationid = l.id where a.id in ()`"

Please give me the solution

Comment: It seems like the variable `(".$pc.")` is empty. From the error you got, it is evaluated as `where a.id in ()`.

Comment: $pc is empty in your query. Please look at the error.

Comment: You try to find integer inside of a string

Comment: @GilPeretz: I know how it can be sometimes when you can't see the wood for the trees. But if you take a closer look at the error message, it might just help you to find the answer to your question. :)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps try something like:

```
SELECT a.`studentcode` , a.`studentname` , a.fathername, a.date, 
       c.`centrename` , cm.`feename` , l.`location`, 
       a.periodofissue, a.image 
FROM admission a 
INNER JOIN centre c ON a.centreid = c.id 
INNER JOIN coursemaster cm ON a.courseid = cm.id 
INNER JOIN location l ON a.locationid = l.id 
where a.id in (select id from admission where id = ".$pc.")
```

or alternatively:

```
SELECT a.`studentcode` , a.`studentname` , a.fathername, a.date, 
       c.`centrename` , cm.`feename` , l.`location`, 
       a.periodofissue, a.image 
FROM admission a 
INNER JOIN centre c ON a.centreid = c.id 
INNER JOIN coursemaster cm ON a.courseid = cm.id 
INNER JOIN location l ON a.locationid = l.id 
where a.id = ".$pc."
```